# Python Pandas: dropping all null columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

Importing a sql datatable as a pandas dataframe and dropping all completely empty columns:

```
equip = %sql select * from [coswin].[dbo].[Work Order]
df = equip.DataFrame()
#dropping empty columns 
df.dropna(axis=1, how="all", inplace=True)
```

the problem is I am still finding the null columns without any errors in the output.

Comment: You may want to look at the "pandasql" library. It allows you to manipulate the df like it is a SQL table using the SQLite language variant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the columns you want to remove are full of null values? You might check with `df.isna().sum()` if you haven't.

Also, you could use `pd.read_sql()` to read your data directly into a DataFrame.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html